# How to write equation to explain this case?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I explain the following case as a math equation: 
I have 3 variables (A, B and C) which contain different values every time, I want to say that value of X (the current variable value) equal to the greatest value of my previous variables (A or B or C).

Thanks in advance

Comment: $X={\rm max}\{|A|,|B|,|C|\}$?

Comment: Why we need to use absolute value here ?

Comment: You didn't say anything about positive or negative, so I thought you wanted positive $X$.

Comment: Oh yes! The values are rational numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use $X=\max(A,B,C)$, noting that all three are different.

Comment: I did not think about equation in this point of view. But it is a better solution for my case. Thank you very much